# How to design forget password Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation

I am going to design the "forget Password" Link

in loginPage.jsp I have :-

```
<form name="testForm" action="passwordValidationController" method="post">
  User Id: <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId"><br>
   .
   .
   .

</form> 


<a href="forgetPasswordController">Click for forget password</a>

. 
.
.
```

---

forgetPasswordController.java

```
doPost(.........)
{



//I want to get the "userId" (textbox value) here

}
```

My question is that:-  how can I get the value of "userId" (textbox) of LoginPage.jsp in the "forgetPasswordController" (servlet) when I click on the "Click for forget password" hyper link?

Please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

@R Chatterjee While clicking the hyperlink, open dialog box and show the form to get the values like login id, emailid and secret question with answer. Finally when they clicking button send those values by jQuery ajax. All yuo need to do is include the jQuery plugin. Here your html may looks like this,

```
<a href="#" onclick="return openForm();">Forgetten your Password?</a>
```

This will open hidden dialog form,

```
function openForm() {
//This Script is used for load pop up div to forgot password screen
$("#dialog").css({
    "display" : "block"
});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    minWidth : 600,
    modal : true
});
}
```

This function will show the dialog box div,

```
<div id="dialog" title="Forgot Password" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="userLogin" id="userLogin" class="text-box">
    <input type="text" name="userEmailId" id="userEmailId"
                class="text-box">
    <input type="button" value="Send" class="btn"
        onclick="sendEmail();" />
</div>
```

jQuery ajax to send parameters to servlet,

```
function sendEmail() {

    var loginId = $('#userLogin').val();
    var emailId = $('#userEmailId').val();

    if (loginId != '' && emailId != '' ) {

        $.ajax({
            url : "forgetPasswordController&userLogin=" + loginId
                    + "&userEmailId=" + emailId,
            async : false,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                $('#userLogin').val('');
                $('#userEmailId').val('');
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        //Display error message
    }
}
```

By the way this is one kind of implementation. You can grab some idea from this.